# Javascript remove last square brackets [ ] in string

Tags: javascript, brackets, square-bracket

How to remove last square brackets. I have string like this:

```
Product[parameter][0][values][2][value]
```

And I need to achive string without last brackets:

```
Product[parameter][0][values][2]
```

Comment: The site works this way: provide a code that is not working exactly as you expect, and other users will try to provide you solutions. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var x = "Product[parameter][0][values][2][value]";
x = x.substr(0, x.lastIndexOf("["));
alert(x);
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/518cpkb8/)**